Dua for breaking fast
Is the dua to be said at the time of Iftar required? Also, what is the correct time to say the dua, before breaking my fast or after? Lately I have been finishing Iftar first and then making the dua.

Abu Huraira (radiallahu ta’ala anhu) reported that Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu alayhi wasallam) said, “Whatever is prayed for at the time of breaking the fast is granted and never refused.” Abu Huraira (radiallahu ta’ala anhu) also reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “The supplications of three are never turned back: a fasting person until he breaks his fast, a just leader, and the supplication of the oppressed is raised above the clouds by Allah, the gates of heaven open for it and the Lord says: By My might, I will surely help you in due time.” [Tirmidhi and Ahmad]
Making dua like this is good before, during or after breaking the fast is good but just before is better. After breaking the fast, the Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) also used to recite, “Dhahaba Zama-u-wabtallatil 'urooqu,
wa tha-batal ajru in-shaa Allah.”
(The thirst is gone and the veins are moistened and the reward is guaranteed, if Allah wills.) [Abu Dawood] This dua is sunnah and recommended but it is not required.

What you're doing is right, you should say bismillah before you break your fast, then after you break your fast recite the du'a CMIIW
